# Populating email value with Owin.Security.Providers.Yahoo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin, yahoo-api

I am using the Yahoo Owin security provider to authenticate my web application users using Yahoo.  They are able to authenticate correctly, however, the Email property is always null.  How do I configure this provider so that the ExternalLoginInfo.Email property is set after the call to `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync`?  My authentication configuration is setup like this:

```
app.UseYahooAuthentication(new YahooAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
    AuthenticationType = "Yahoo",
    BackchannelTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
    Caption = "Yahoo",
    ConsumerKey = yahooKey,
    ConsumerSecret = yahooSecret,
    Provider = new YahooAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = context =>
        {
            foreach (var claim in context.User)
            {
                var claimType = $"urn:yahoo:{claim.Key}";
                var claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Yahoo"));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

}